# Wordpress is not getting the correct image thumbnail size

Tags: php, wordpress, image, base64

So I have some code in my functions file to create the custom image size:

```
add_image_size( 'tiny_thumb', 10, 10, false );
```

now in the template file I need to get that tiny thumb so I can generate a base64 image from the url:

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postId, 'tiny_thumb');
$ext = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
```

Now the problem is that for some images it's getting the tiny thumb, 10x10 image. But for others the full size image is used. I have checked and for the images where the full size image is used there is a 10x10 version of that image. So does exists.

Anyone know why it might be doing this.

The reason I need it to use the tiny thumb to generate the base64 image is if it uses full size image the generated base64 html is really large size.

Hope this make sense

Cheers

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the 10x10 images that aren't showing are not associated with the "tiny-thumb" name. Would you have created them using a different name? But based on the information you provided, it should be working. We don't know the rest of your code or setup, so you'll need to do some more investigating to find whats causing the issue yourself, and come back with the details after you find it if you have trouble fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so figured out whats going on.
The images that were using the 10x10 image size had been uploaded after the new image size was created(so when a new post was created). So the images were associated with the `tiny_thumb`.

I had used the regenerate thumbnails plugin on my localhost, then uploaded the new image sizes to the live site. But doing it this way the 10x10 images were not associated with tiny thumb.

The Solution.
I had to run the regenerate thumbnails plugin on our live site to associate all the 10x10 image sizes with `tiny_thumb`

Thanks fluffykitten for helping out :)